# Add meta tag for Pinterest Accounts verification for magento site

Tags: magento

I want to add meta tag for Pinterest Account verification for my magneto site. I added it in
`System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML head -> Miscellaneous Scripts`. But it doesn't appear in the page source. Does it require anything more setting to do?

Answer (score 0):

then you have to put the script in

```
app/code/design/frontend/[package]/[template-name]/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you... It is working fine when added in header.phtml.. But I just wanted to check that can we manage it from admin side...

Comment: in header.phtml ..use this code <?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('script_id')->toHtml(); ?>

then create a static block at backend, menu CMS->Static Blocks ..with identifier is 'script_id'